# Authentication issue while trying to connect to mongo on Docker from Spring data mongodb

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo instance running on docker container. I am trying to connect to it from a spring mvc application using xml configuration.

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="hname" port="27017" credential="user:pwd@dbname"/>
  <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="dbname" mongo-client-ref="mongoClient" />
  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoClient"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="dbname"/>
  </bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="xxx.yyy.zzz.core.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />
```

When I run the container I see an error saying:

Error! Query failed with error code 13 with name 'Unauthorized' and error message 'not authorized on dbname to execute command { find: "attributes", filter: { unique_user_id: "iTrustUIN" }, limit: 2, $db: "dbname", lsid: { id: UUID("bc5daa8c-8fc7-44da-8b8c-0fa91384cbd8") } }' on server dbname:27017;}}

what am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.
Note: I have couple of **springboot** applications and I can successfully connect to the mongo from those.

My pom.xml

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

thanks,
Pbale

Comment: can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Finally, I could able to make it work. my pom.xml has

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could able to make it work.
pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

applicationConetext.xml:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" connection-string="mongodb://user:pwd@host:27017/dbname"/>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
<mongo:repositories
  base-package="edu.illinois.sample.spring.data" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/> 
<bean id="attrImpl" class="edu.illinois.sample.spring.data.AttributesDaoImpl"/>
```

java code:

```
try (FileSystemXmlApplicationContext actx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(springConfig)) {
    AttributesDaoImpl attrImpl = actx.getBean(AttributesDaoImpl.class);
    try {
       Attributes attr = attrImpl.getAttributesByUniqueUserId("iTrustUIN");
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
```